# How to hide some items from DrawerNavigator. I want that only a few appear

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Also, I want to add a button to exit.

[image]

```
     <DrawerNavigatorItems
          {...props}
          itemsContainerStyle={{width: '100%'}}
      />
```

Comment: can up  code in expo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tipos:{
  screen:Tipos,
  navigationOptions:{
    title: 'Tipos',
    drawerLabel: ()=>null
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

button to exit

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
    <Button title={"exit"} onPress={() => {
        //do exit
    }} ></Button>
</View>
```